# Why doesn't this nth-of-type selector to work

Tags: css

I am trying to get the nth-of-type selector to style the 3rd Article element, but it's not making any difference to it

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  Height: 1000px;
}

article:nth-of-type (3) {
  flex: 3 200px;
  display: flex;
}

article {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  Padding: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  Flex: 1 200px;
}

header {
  background: pink;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  Margin: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Hello
</header>
<section>
  <article>
    Hello
  </article>
  <article>
    Hello
  </article>
  <article>
    <div>
      hello
    </div>
    <div>
      hello
    </div>

    <div>
      hello
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

I am trying to style the 3rd Article element using nth-of-type but the nth-of-type- selector and it's rules make no difference to the 3rd article  element. I am trying to give it a flex value of 3 so that it's a little bigger than the first 2

Comment: This is my first time asking a question on here I am a real newbie, please let me know if I need to improve this type of post in some way, or if I have neglected to do/add something

Comment: no space `nth-of-type (3)` --> `nth-of-type(3)`

Answer (score 0):

Remove space like this :

Change :

```
article:nth-of-type (3) {
//                 ^-------------
//Rules...
}
```

To :

```
article:nth-of-type(3) {
 //Rules...
}
```

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  Height: 1000px;
}

article:nth-of-type(3) {
  flex: 3 200px;
  display: flex;
  background:orange;
}

article {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  Padding: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  Flex: 1 200px;
}

header {
  background: pink;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  Margin: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Hello
</header>
<section>
  <article>
    Hello
  </article>
  <article>
    Hello
  </article>
  <article>
    <div>
      hello
    </div>
    <div>
      hello
    </div>

    <div>
      hello
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is because you have an extra space between `:nth-of-type` and `(3)`.

You should use `:nth-of-type(3)` instead.